# RSA short key generation using OpenSSL

Tags: rsa, openssl

To write a CTF challenge, I want to create an RSA key pair of size 228-bit. I want the keys exactly in the same format as OpenSSL-generated keys. But, OpenSSL is not supporting less than 512-bit long keys. What could be a solution?

Answer (score 2):

In the end you'll have to program it I suppose, here's a small Java application that creates a PEM encoded RSA PRIVATE KEY (unencrypted PKCS#1 structure) and PUBLIC KEY (X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo).

Obviously it is build on top of the Bouncy Castle provider for Java / JCA and the `PemWriter` from the "lightweight" API that is part of the provider package.

```
package com.stackexchange.crypto;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Object;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter;

public class ShortRsaKeyPair {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); 
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        kpg.initialize(228);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        
        PrivateKeyInfo privKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.getInstance(kp.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
        ASN1Object pkcs1Object = (ASN1Object) privKeyInfo.parsePrivateKey(); 
        try (PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(new FileWriter("privkey.pem"))) {
            pemWriter.writeObject(new PemObject("RSA PRIVATE KEY", pkcs1Object.getEncoded("DER")));
        }
 
        // not needed, you can also generate it from the private key using "openssl rsa -pubout"
        try (PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(new FileWriter("pubkey.pem"))) {
            pemWriter.writeObject(new PemObject("PUBLIC KEY", kp.getPublic().getEncoded()));
        }
    }
}
```

You can check the result using:

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in pubkey.pem -text
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -text
```

Answer (score 2):

The format of RSA private keys is described in [PKCS#1 V2.2 appendix A.1.2](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=41). OpenSSL can be told to output a key in that format with PEM formatting over that, so that the resulting data is text; that's practice for RSA private keys when not encrypted.

The code for this given $(p,q,e)$ is one page of Python (with no assurance of correctness) in this [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##jZNra9swFIa/61ccUkbkWkl9jzzSQbeaEcayko7BYFCcSUnMGlm2lC6B/vdMcp043V0fbOmco/d9ZB/JnV6VIqSy3u/P4MNGy42GXMDs9gpkXTzkmsM3voNCwE32HhZlvc41QmcwEaYSSbgEn6Z@lERxmtDYH8WJH0QeDcMgSVKaBnHqhSNU2bokGNE48Lw0DKgXpt4oirwojfzQi9M0NasR4qYuiWOzw1i8KdfGg4Necai50kiYrDyvELPv8jvmZOATLAe@c44r83QQs0DsRRNDrHpa2BSqinZTZTdJxxpc3U6HPlxnM@Dia8kKsUSLulzDPFc8iaBYy7LWTzk@32muEOMLyJXw77nAmmydlwjMUEbaRrZOsywWgNXYD2ibtqPmelMLwHo8po/KGeryrlHEAenPi2XfcbdNbW2ksBrOC31nFJd6hR135FxcUPSLirel3mP9OynVxepO/sBeCI1Fi5Yrxc0RxatLj0BP8GWuiweuQJQaVrlg95z1Tp0PZw@I6DzEM1zD6vqtq3M0rVVu2wkLwgkjklSEScIqUhUtyU8GESUHVs9xO@zjlHdT1k1lN61OCk7C7CRuzJs@sJ197ABLLPn6f4HnvYEdr7O3k2lza25mk09XHzN4l31uMl9Ezz1pIfyPr@G4rWI2vf6TnmVur@ozdKNpv8Ff4YeMWxbc3@jFgNpftN//AA)

One can [parse the result with Lapo Luchini's ASN.1 JavaScript decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIGbAgEAAh0La7VhmAtKjGz5JEnapcSsPkyFNHaCBMEy0HOCywIDAQABAh0BFqTUxk7dLgD8xa6cPguZF7_0VoQMXLM2m9Ie8QIPA6SQZVZ2RmZvverMQdkdAg8DIpfPPjdoy_TGKH8fbwcCDwN31ylDidM4j0XmlpRSWQIPAwcJ4IitS1cBpcX_lKRLAg8DM9eFJ_V52jelxc6-DFQ).

With the private key in `private.pem`, OpenSSL can generate the public key with

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
```

One can also [parse the result with said ASN.1 JavaScript decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MDgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADJwAwJAIdC2u1YZgLSoxs-SRJ2qXErD5MhTR2ggTBMtBzgssCAwEAAQ).